# Class variables and static methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods

I am observing a behavior, would like to know the reason behind the functionality.

```
class Employee:
  raise_amount = 1.04
  def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.pay = pay
  @classmethod
  def set_raise_amt(cls, amount):
    cls.raise_amount = amount

 emp_1 = Employee("John","Booth",8000)
 emp_2 = Employee("Satya","Ch",9000)
 emp_1.raise_amount = 4.05
 print (emp_1.raise_amount)
 emp_1.set_raise_amt(3.00)
 print (emp_1.raise_amount)
 print (emp_2.raise_amount)
```

Above is my code. When executed below output is given

```
4.05

4.05

3.0

[Finished in 0.3s]
```

My confusion is when I have set the value of `emp_1.raise_amount` to 3.00 using the static method, why did it not reflect in the print statement? And how come the value of `emp_2.raise_amount` got changed to 3.00?

Comment: Because you've shadowed the class attribute with an instance attribute on `emp_1`.

Comment: Hi Jonrsharpe, can you please elaborate on what shadowing actually means. Based on the duplicated query you pasted above. I tried the following {Employee.raise_amount = 3.0} and then tried doing {print emp_1.raise-amount, print emp_2.raise_amount}. Yet still got the same output. So why is it that when we change the value of a class variable using the class directly, the value assigned through the class instance remains unchanged. Thanks

Comment: I see identical behaviour using `Employee.raise_amount = amount`, `Employee.set_raise_amt(amount)` and `emp_x.set_raise_amt(amount)`, as expected. Also note you mark code with backticks `\`\``, not braces `{}`.